# Creating Repository with Objective-Git

Tags: git, cocoa, libgit2, objective-git

I am trying to create a Git repository using [objective-git](https://github.com/libgit2/objective-git). The documentation is somewhat lacking on how the GT classes work together to create a repository so I'm kind of stuck.

This is what I have working so far:

```
GTRepository *newRepo = [GTRepository initializeEmptyRepositoryAtFileURL:repoURL error:&error]
```

I then copy a bunch of files into that directory. I can open then the repo in a Git client and see those files in the working directory. Everything looks good so far. But this is where I'm stuck, what is my next move to actually create a branch and commit those files?

EDIT: I have now gotten the GTIndex from my GTRepository (though, the fileURL property of the index is still nil, so I'm not sure how to generate that file). I iterate through my files, calling `addFile:error:` which creates GTIndexEntries in my index. I then call `writeTree:` and get back a GTTree that I pass into `[repository createCommitWithTree:newTree message:@"Initial Commit" parents:nil updatingReferenceNamed:nil error:&error];`. This returns a valid GTCommit object and no NSError, but I would expect that [repository headReferenceWithError:&error]; would now return a reference to the newly created commit, but it still returns nil. Is there a step I am missing to finalize this commit?

Comment: Do you really want to create an index or load the repository's existing index with something like `[repository indexWithError:NULL]` ?

Comment: I didn't see the index file so I assumed I had to create my own, but I see that indexWithError does return a valid GTIndex. Now I will attempt to use addFile: and writeTree: using the index, instead of using GTTreeBuilder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like there's a [`[GTReference referenceByCreatingReferenceNamed:name]`](https://github.com/libgit2/objective-git/blob/bf7b88552f262a19f89b36eb43ecc2cfe0f9ffff/Classes/GTReference.h#L61) static method. [Here's an example](https://github.com/libgit2/objective-git/blob/bf7b88552f262a19f89b36eb43ecc2cfe0f9ffff/ObjectiveGitTests/GTReferenceSpec.m#L59) of how you use it.

Comment: both of these methods eventually call the function git_reference_lookup() that searches for an existing reference with that name. I have no existing references

Comment: Rats. Well, I guess you could always just call `git_reference_create`: http://libgit2.github.com/libgit2/#HEAD/group/reference/git_reference_create

Comment: that's true, I'd just like to stick to Objective-Git if possible

Comment: Edited: check out `[GTReference referenceByCreatingReferenceNamed:name]`!

Comment: Yes!! That did it, you pass in the @"refs/heads/branchName" as name  and the SHA of some commit as the reference target parameter. Then passing that ref to GTBranch initWithReference:repository: and then check out the ref with the repo and boom, you've got an initial commit and the master branch checked out.